# In Visual Studio 2015, clicking on the .cs class is taking me to the .designer.cs file instead of the cs file

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2015

I'm not exactly sure when this started happening, but it seems like it started happening after applying Update 3, but it may be related to an extension or something... but now in a WinForms application, when I click on the .cs class node in the Solution Explorer (it's under the *.designer.cs file in the three, and has the orange 'class' icon next to it), instead of taking me to the .cs class as it always has in the past, it takes me to the .designer.cs class ... which is completely useless.  It is basically duplicating the function of clicking on the *.designer.cs node right above it.

If I expand the .cs class node and click on any of the elements there (properties, methods, etc) it goes to the right file. I'm finding this really frustrating, and I can't find any setting or anything that changed, nor is there any mention on the internet that I can find about anyone else having this problem. I just want to get the old behavior back, and I'm really at a loss... is this a "just me" thing, is it happening to anyone else, is it a VS2015 bug introduced, or is there some extension I have that is mucking things up?

I'm using ReSharper (latest version), VS Commands for 2015 (even though it's barely functional compared to previous versions), Productivity Power Tools 2015, Rename Visual Studio Window Title, ... plus the standard ones I see in any install.

I just want to get the functionality back of being able to easily get to the *.cs file by double-clicking on it in solution explorer.  Can anyone help?

Comment: I never knew it did that.  I just tested it and it brought me to the designer but more importantly to a specific spot in the designer.  The spot it is linked to which is the partial class spot.  If I double click the .Designer.cs it just opens it.  Doesn't go anywhere special.  It seems like it is linked to the class in the designer.  I just right click on the Form and click view code.

Comment: I've always just been able to double-click on the class name and go directly to the class.  Being able to go to the designer is ... dumb. There's never any need to do that. Ever. I never want to see that file. It's pointless. I do all my work in the *.cs class, the designer is all GENERATED code!  This worked fine up until relatively recently. I'm not sure if it was with the switch to 2015 from 2013, or with the application of update 3. Or something else.